# Implementar la función eliminar en PSeInt

Tags: funciones, pseint, substring, pseudocódigo

Este programa en pseudocódigo PSeInt pretende implementar la función eliminar, que consiste en quitar o borrar una subcadena de una cadena mayor

Sintaxis: eliminar (Cadena, índice, cantidad)

Ejemplo: La sentencia Escribir eliminar(cad, índice, cantidad); cuando índice = 13 y cantidad = 3 y la variable cad cargada con la cadena "Programación 1" debería Escribir la cadena "Programación"

Otro ejemplo:
La cadena "Hola como estás" con índice = 3 y cantidad = 3 debería devolver la cadena "Holomo estás"

Tengo este código, pero marca error

```
Proceso sintitulo
    Definir cad, cadenafinal Como cadena;
    Definir tam, indice, cantidad Como Enteros;
    Escribir "Favor ingresar la cadena: ";
    Leer cad;
    Escribir "Favor ingresar posición inicial de corte: ";
    Leer indice;
    Escribir "Favor ingresar cantidad de caracteres a eliminar: ";
    Leer cantidad;
    Escribir eliminar(cad, indice, cantidad);
FinProceso

SubProceso cadenafinal <- eliminar(cad,indice,cantidad)
    Definir i, tam Como Entero;
    Dimension cadenafinal[100];
    Definir cadenafinal Como Cadena;
    tam <- longitud(cad)-1;
    cadenafinal<-"";

    // Copia el inicio de la cadena
    Para i <- 0 hasta indice Hacer
        cadenafinal[i] <- cad[i];
    FinPara

    Mientras indice <= tam Hacer
        Si indice + cantidad >= tam Entonces
            cadenafinal[indice] <- cad[indice + cantidad];
        FinSi
        indice<-indice+1;
    FinMientras
FinSubProceso
```

Answer (score 0):

El código corregido quedaría así

```
Proceso sintitulo
    Definir indice, cantidad Como Enteros;
    Definir cad, cadenaresultante Como Cadenas;
    
    Escribir "Ingrese la cadena :";
    Leer cad;
    
    Escribir "Introduzca la posición para iniciar la extracción: ";
    Leer indice;
    
    Escribir "Ingrese la longitud de la subcadena: ";
    Leer cantidad;
    
    cadenaresultante <- eliminar(cad, indice, cantidad);
    
    Escribir cadenaresultante;
FinProceso

SubProceso Retorno <- eliminar(str, pos, l)
    Definir tam Como Entero;
    Definir retorno, sstr Como Cadenas;
    tam <- Longitud(str);
    
    sstr <- "";
    
    // Copia el inicio de la cadena hasta la posición desde donde se quiere remover
    Si pos > 1 Entonces
        sstr <- SubCadena(str, 0, pos-1); //Si se quiere adaptar para base 1, se debe cambiar el 0 de esta línea por 1
    FinSi
    
    // Añade el resto de la cadena después de la parte removida
    Si pos + l <= tam Entonces
        sstr <- concatenar(sstr,SubCadena(str, pos + l, tam));
    FinSi
    
    Retorno <- sstr;
FinSubProceso
```